# How to close a dropdown when click outside in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a **drop-down with dynamic data**, when user **click outside the drop-down is not closed** until we select something from drop-down. My drop-down has autocomplete functionality too.

[image]
**component.html**

```
<div class="form-field col-lg-12 ">
        <label class="label" for="company">Publication</label>

        <input [(ngModel)]="pubTitleKeyUp" (ngModelChange)="keyUpPublication(pubTitleKeyUp)" name="pub"
            class="input-text js-input" type="text" required autocomplete="off" >


        <div class="search-result" *ngIf="publications" style="max-height: 120px;">
            <ul style="margin:0; padding:5px;">
                <li *ngFor="let pub of publications">
                    <a (click)="onClickPublication(pub)"> {{ pub.Title }} -{{ pub.city }} </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
    ngOnInit(): void {


    /* API Call for publications when page load */

this.article.postPublication(null).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.allPubs = data.result;
      console.log(this.publications);
    });
  }

  onFocusPublication() {
    console.log(this.selectedDate);
  }

  /* POST article with PUB id and Date */

  keyUpPublication(e) {
    let k = e as string
    let kl = k.length

    this.publications = this.allPubs.filter(p => {
      // let title = p.Title.toLowerCase()
      // return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase()

    let title = p.Title + ' -' + p.city;
    return title.toLowerCase().includes(k.toLowerCase());
    })
  }

  onClickPublication(pub: IPub) {
    this.pubTitleKeyUp = pub.Title + ' -' + pub.city;
    this.selectedPub = pub
    this.publications = []
  } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way using `HostListener` it worked :

```
<div class="form-field col-lg-12 ">
    <label class="label" for="company">Publication</label>

    <input [(ngModel)]="pubTitleKeyUp" (ngModelChange)="keyUpPublication(pubTitleKeyUp)" name="pub"
        class="input-text js-input" type="text" required autocomplete="off" >


    <div class="search-result" *ngIf="publications || isFocus" style="max-height: 120px;" id= "dropdownList">
        <ul style="margin:0; padding:5px;">
            <li *ngFor="let pub of publications">
                <a (click)="onClickPublication(pub)"> {{ pub.Title }} -{{ pub.city }} </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
  isFocus : boolean = false;

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickOut(event) {
      if (event.target.id != 'dropdownList' && event.target.name != 'pub') 
      {
        this.isFocus= false;
      }
   }

   keyUpPublication(e) {
     let k = e as string
     let kl = k.length
     this.isFocus= true;
     this.publications = this.allPubs.filter(p => {
    // let title = p.Title.toLowerCase()
    // return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase()

    let title = p.Title + ' -' + p.city;
    return title.toLowerCase().includes(k.toLowerCase());
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some issues in your design too, could you please try the below code, you need to fix the position first!

```
<div *ngIf="publications && publications.length" (click)="publications = []"
style="position: fixed; right: 0; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0"></div>
```

you need to add this where ever your form is starting and let me know.